# Conditional joint entropy of two random variables

Tags: summation, random-variables, expectation, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to prove the formula that gives the joint entropy of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$ which is:

$$H(X,Y|Z) = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$$

based on the definition of conditional entropy which is:

$$H(Y|X) \triangleq E_{p_{X,Y}}\{-log_2p_{Y|X}(Y|X)\}$$

So if we start from the LHS:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\\H(X,Y|Z) &=& E_{p_{X,Y,Z}}\{-log_2p_{X,Y|Z}(X,Y|Z)\}
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2p_{X,Y|Z=z}(x,y)
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2\{p_{Y|X=x,Z=z}(y)\cdot p_{X|Z=z}(x)\} 
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot \Big[log_2\{p_{Y|X=x,Z=z}(y)\} + log_2\{p_{X|Z=z}(x)\}\Big]
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2\{p_{Y|X=x,Z=z}(y)\}
\\&&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2\{p_{X|Z=z}(x)\}\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2\{p_{Y|X=x,Z=z}(y)\}
\\&&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{z}log_2\{p_{X|Z=z}(x)\}\sum\limits_{y}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) 
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}\sum\limits_{z}p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\cdot log_2\{p_{Y|X=x,Z=z}(y)\}
\\&&-\sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{z}log_2\{p_{X|Z=z}(x)\}p_{X,Z}(x,z) 
\\&=&H(Y|X,Z) + H(X|Z)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hint: From Bayes' theorem, $p_{XY|Z}(x,y|z) = p_{X|Z}(x|z) p_{Y|XZ}(y|x,z)$. Then split the $\log$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 The truth is that I didn't know about this "flavor" of Bayes' theorem and thanks for pointing this out. So I did what you suggested. Can you give one more check?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. You can write it more concisely if you keep everything inside an expectation. 

Also, note that this extends to any finite number of random variables: $P(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) = P(X_1)P(X_2|X_1)\dots P(X_n|X_{n-1}, \dots, X_1)$ Where $P(X)$ is shorthand for $p_X(x)$.